# split a record into multiple records based on watched program category

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, unnest

I recently started using postgres and I am coming from oracle background. Just curious to know if the query I have written can be implemented in a better way in postgres.

Problem Details:

I have two tables:

1. usage_detail
2. Program_info

Usage_detail has information about any user watching a channel. For example user A had its session length for 1 hour 10 mins 0 seconds, starting at 1:15 PM today

```
User  start_time           end_time
A     2016-10-31 13:15:00  2016-10-31 14:25:00
```

Program_info table contains scheduled program detail and corresponding category.

For example:

```
Program_id program_category  week_day   start_time  end_time
         1 News              Monday     13:00       13:30
         2 Sports            Monday     13:30       14:30
```

The output I am looking for is:

```
User  program_category   start_time           duration (in seconds)
   A  News               2016-10-31 13:15:00       900
   A  Sports             2016-10-31 13:30:00      3300
```

My current approach:

I divided the start_time and end_time duration into 30 minutes interval(because program category may change in every 30 mins). Like for the example I mentioned, I first created 3 records (from 1:15 pm to 1:30 pm, 1:30 pm to 2:00pm, 2:00 pm to 2:25 pm) then summed the duration based on program_category.

I wrote a little less readable code, which generates multiple records out of one record dynamically without using postgres' array and unnest functionality.

Can anyone suggest what could be the best way to approach this problem using either Array/unnest or any other functionality available in postgres? I am not looking for exact code, just the direction would do.

Comment: In my part of the world, 2016-10-31 is a Monday not a Sunday.

Comment: I realized it a little later, will edit. Its Diwali time in india, vacations are on, felt like sunday. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to generate any rows. Based on your sample data, you can simply join the two tables.

```
select *
from program_info pi
  join usage_detail ud 
    on to_char(ud.start_time, 'FMday') = lower(pi.week_day) 
   and (pi.start_time, pi.end_time) overlaps (ud.start_time::time, ud.end_time::time)
```

(I used `user_name` instead of `user`, because `user` is a reserved keyword)

Note that the join using `to_char(ud.start_time, 'FMday') = lower(pi.week_day)` requires the weekday to be stored in the same language as `to_char()` will return it. It would be better to store that as a number, not a string.

With that result it's possible to calculate the actual start and end time for each program. This can either be done with a complicated `case when` statement comparing the time information stored in `usage_detail` with that from `program_info` checking which of the start times was the bigger one and which of the end times was the smaller one.

This can however be simplified using a time range. Unfortunately, there is no such range time built in, but it's easy to create:

```
create type timerange as range (subtype = time);
```

With that the actual start and end times can be calculated using the intersection of the two ranges:

```
select ud.user_name, 
       pi.program_id,
       pi.program_category,
       ud.start_time::date as start_day,
       timerange(pi.start_time, pi.end_time) * timerange(ud.start_time::time, ud.end_time::time) as view_interval
from program_info pi
  join usage_detail ud 
    on to_char(ud.start_time, 'FMday') = lower(pi.week_day) 
   and (pi.start_time, pi.end_time) overlaps (ud.start_time::time, ud.end_time::time)
```

The `*` is the [intersection operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-range.html) for ranges. The above returns this:

```
user_name | program_id | program_category | start_day  | view_interval      
----------+------------+------------------+------------+--------------------
A         |          1 | News             | 2016-10-31 | [13:15:00,13:30:00)
A         |          2 | Sports           | 2016-10-31 | [13:30:00,14:25:00)
```

Having the actual viewing time as a range can now be used to get the final display you want:

```
with view_times as (
    select ud.user_name, 
           pi.program_id,
           pi.program_category,
           ud.start_time::date as start_day,
           timerange(pi.start_time, pi.end_time) * timerange(ud.start_time::time, ud.end_time::time) as view_interval
    from program_info pi
      join usage_detail ud 
        on to_char(ud.start_time, 'FMday') = lower(pi.week_day) 
       and (pi.start_time, pi.end_time) overlaps (ud.start_time::time, ud.end_time::time)
)
select user_name, program_id, program_category,
       start_day + lower(view_interval) as actual_start_time,
       extract(epoch from (upper(view_interval) - lower(view_interval))) as duration
from view_times
```

This returns:

```
user_name | program_id | program_category | actual_start_time   | duration
----------+------------+------------------+---------------------+---------
A         |          1 | News             | 2016-10-31 13:15:00 |      900
A         |          2 | Sports           | 2016-10-31 13:30:00 |     3300
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/VNXIG64065

Comment: Awesome stuff, Thanks alot. I had to do minor changes as on boundary conditions for time(23:45 to 00:15), it gave error as it couldn't understand the upper bound is for next day's time. I added date part into it, used inbuilt tsrange and everything worked.